# Splash in activity or thread?

Tags: android, splash-screen

So I've currently been using splash in a thread and now I consider using it in an activity instead. The reason I used it in a thread was to do stuff in the background while it was displayed.

The reason I'm considering using an activity instead is that I'll be able to show the splash in fullscreen and then when I switch to my main activity let the notification bar be displayed again. I'll off course use the splash activity to do all possible background data.

This is not a question about how to implement but rather the cons and pros of this approach, all feedback is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Cons of using a splash screen**

1. It is orthogonal to how Android apps usually operate

   If you haven't noticed, almost none of the built-in apps have splash screens (the only prominent example is Google Maps Navigation). Generally apps are designed to show a screen to the user immediately then load data in while presenting the user with some options (see Google Maps).
2. It is annoying to users

   Splash screens make the top of the list on [What are common UI misconceptions and annoyances?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1011285/984393)

I say this as a user of apps who is often put off by splash screens. They are especially bothersome because I want to switch apps rapidly and they prevent me from doing so.

Perhaps you could implement a scheme where you display your main page, and have a widget on that page showing the loading progress. That is more user friendly in my opinion. Your goal should be get out of `onCreate` as soon as possible leaving a responsive UI for the user. The Amazon Appstore is a good example: it shows all the headers and then loads in the apps and images while you play around with things.

**If have no choice**

Pros of using a Thread for a splash screen

1. It simplifies concerns over lifecycle

   If you use an Activity, you will have to make sure it is not on the stack so that users cannot navigate back to it ([Android: 'Splash screen' only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3625394/android-splash-screen-only-once)).
2. It simplifies the logic of starting this activity

   You won't have to worry about when or where to start the splash Activity. Your other Activities can call the Activity with a splash screen normally, and you won't have to switch back and forth between the splash Activity and your actual activity
3. You don't have to worry about the splash Activity as an entity

   It just leaves you with an Activity that takes longer to start up

Comment: Sometimes you get dictated design by customers and you are forced to do things :) even though you recommend differently, this is one of them for me. I agree with you but it doesn't answer my question :)

Comment: @Warpzit fair enough... I added my thoughts on Thread vs. Activity splash screens