# Kill Splash Screen When Click "BACK" Button

Tags: android, splash-screen, activity-lifecycle

I have created a splash screen for my android app. My question is simple. After 5 seconds splash screen disappear and main activity works. Then if i click "Back" button it returns splash screen again. But i don't want this.

If user touch "Back" button on mainactivity, app must go android menu without splash screen. How can i fix it?

```java
package com.example.androidfirst;

import android.app.Activity;

public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

    Thread timer = new Thread() {   //new Thread
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                sleep(5000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                Intent MainAct = new Intent("com.example.androidfirst.MAINACTIVITY");
                startActivity(MainAct);

                try {
                    this.finalize();
                }
                catch (Throwable e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

    };

    timer.start();

}

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: 'Splash screen' only once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3625394/android-splash-screen-only-once)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If user touch "Back" button on mainactivity, app must go android menu without splash screen. How can i fix it?

You might find using a [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and [Runnable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html) an easier way to create a delay, but simply call `finish()` after `startActivity()`.

Answer (score 6):

You can implement in your **AndroidManifest.xml** with `android:noHistory="true"` in `<activity>` tag for Splash Screen.

Comment: This one is actually the best method. Thanks @Thu Thu

Answer (score 3):

First of all, don't use splash screens.

Nevertheless, you have to call `finish()` and or start the new activity with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`.

Comment: If you're actually loading data you should use one.  And its not always your choice-  management loves them.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to add `onStop()` to specify what to be done when the splash screen is no longer visible.

Call `finish()` from there.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advise you against using a splash screen just for the sake of having a splash screen.

If you've got some long running task that you need to do before you are ready to show the UI to the user (i.e. loading data from some source), then showing a splash while you are loading that data is appropriate. Otherwise you are simply wasting your users time.

5 seconds doesn't seem like a long time, but while your users are sitting there staring at a useless splash screen for that time it will seem like an eternity to them.

If you feel like you must use a splash screen please read and absorb the knowledge on this page: [SplashScreens Done Right](http://blog.iangclifton.com/2011/01/01/android-splash-screens-done-right/)

Once you've read that follow the examples that he uses so as to at least annoy your users as little as possible.

Comment: This is only example for my Android course. I'am learning base things of Android but thanks for advices. :)

Comment: You should still study the example given on the page I linked. And you might consider sharing with your class that using a splash screen when you don't have anything specific to do during the time it is essentially wasting the time of your users =)