# Why sleep() method is not absolute value while working?

Tags: android

```
public static void sleep (long time)
```

This is from android [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) in Eclipse;

"Causes the thread which sent this message to sleep for the given interval of time (given in milliseconds). The precision is not guaranteed - the Thread may sleep more or less than requested."

**What does it mean thread may sleep more or less than requested. Why it is not absolute while working with this method?**

Comment: I [still recommend](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14841949/1267661) using a [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and [Runnable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html) instead, you _really_ should look into them.

Comment: @Sam while in principle I don't disagree, a `Handler` and `Runnable` are going to have just as many problems with precision as `sleep`. @hakiko it means the sleep time will not be exactly what you asked for but in reality it'll be fairly close if you're asking for a sleep on the order of seconds. I would be pretty shocked if a call to `sleep` was off by more than a few hundred ms.

Answer (score 3):

It is not absolute for several reasons, the main one being that we can't measure time all that accurately. Also, it may have to wait for more high priority threads to ease up before it is allowed to cut in again.

This problem is not specific to Android, but to any thread in general even on desktop computers, and the reasons are explained very well over [here](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/sleep.shtml).

Comment: It extends beyond java even -- I believe [sleep is typically a syscall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep_(operating_system\)), and it's up to the OS to resume execution whenever it has a chance, so to speak. "It is up to the scheduler's discretion, and dependent on thread priorities and implementation details such as timer resolutions when the sleeping thread will run again"

Comment: @FrankFarmer Thank you for that. I haven't worked with any language other than Java in years well enough to be sure, so I didn't put it into the answer. I'll edit it now :)