# back button's function on first activity

Tags: android, android-activity, back-button

Normally when the back button is clicked it goes to the previous activity and if the current activity is the first activity, the application closes.

I have a splash screen (that is logically my first activity) and then the menu activity loads.

I want to close the program when the back button is pressed on my menu activity (as if it is the first activity) and avoid going back to the splash screen again, but I know that I should not exit the program.

I was wondering what is the functionality of back button on the first activity?
does it put the program to pause?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3625394/android-splash-screen-only-once

Comment: @Nuwan94 best solution +1....but I suggest to add a view group contains the splash screen and show it in his menu activity `using Handler` for some time then hiding it

Comment: @Ashkan Add finish() code in splash screen activity after start firstactivity code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. [Avoid splash screens](https://cyrilmottier.com/2012/05/03/splash-screens-are-evil-dont-use-them/) !
2. Instead of using your splash as the main activity, use menu activity as the main one, and in `onCreate()` chain off the splash activity, which will close and disappear forever.

Comment: For 1st point, the article comes from 2012 and is a POV. But think if you need to load some resources from a RESTful URL.

For the 2nd one I agree. The main activity is the main activity. A splash screen is a splash screen.

Answer (score 2):

When new Activity is launched from first Activity, first Activity is executed until onStop() method, then it stops and waits for relaunch, unless you killed it by calling .finish(), in that case launched Activity becomes first Activity and back button will minimize application on back button press. In order to control what application does on back button press you can override this method in your Activities and implement your own custom behaviour:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed()
}
```

---

Very good example of how lifecycle of Fragments/Activities work can be seen in picture below:

[image]

---

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

While you are on the SplashScreen, on the method calling your menu activity I assume you are doing something like `startActivity (new Intent (this, MenuActivity.class));`  in `Java` or `startActivity(Intent(this, MenuActivity::class.java))` for `Kotlin` just after that call `finish()` this will remove your SplashScreen from the back stack

Answer (score 1):

add this attribute to your splash activity (in manifest):

`android:excludeFromRecents="true"`

pressing back in per activity, transfer control to prev activity in stack (back stack) that not excluded from "Recents".